# Dojo scrollableview stops moving to original place if tapped with multiple fingers simultaneously

Tags: dojo, dojox.mobile

I am using Titanium for my app that runs on an iPad. We follow hybrid approach. I have a Dojo scrollableview that shows a list of suppliers. When a user drags the scrollableview to the bottom and simultaneoulsy taps anywhere on the scrollableview with another finger anywhere on the scrollableview without moving the first tap the scrollableview position sticks to that position and does not move to its original position. This behavior occurs only when multiple simultaneous taps are done. How do i make the scrollableview move to its original position when such situation happens?

Comment: Do you mean that when the user scroll after the last element of the scrollableview (after the bottom of the view) and touch the screen with another finger, the scroll stops and the view is not "bouncing back" as it would have if the user simply released its finger after scrolling ? What version of dojo do you use ?

Comment: 1.8.3 version..yes exactly